# How to replicate a specific observation from a single variable in SAS?

Tags: sas

I want to do a CPI adjustment to US Dollars in a specific year, for instance, 2018. So I want to multiply my series by the factor CPI_2018/CPI_t , where t is the index for any observation's year. I have thought to do this by first creating a variable in my CPI dataset, containing only the CPI for 2018.

How could I take the 2018 observation for my CPI dataset and replicate it to all years in that dataset, as a separate variable? My data looks as in the shown image[image]

Comment: It depends a lot on your data structure. Can you post examples of what you have and what you want?

Comment: Hi Reeza, variables are: year cpi .No missing observations, no missing years. Want to take a ratio of the cpi relative to 2014. Thought to first make a variable equal to the 2014 cpi in all observations. How would you do this? Or woudl you do it differently? Added an image of the data to my original question.

Comment: Please provide sample data as text.

Answer (score 0):

```
data want;
set have;
if _n_ = 1 then set have(where=(year=2018) rename=CPI=CPI_2018 keep = CPI);

run;
```

The second set statement will merge the data in the data for the selected year. This is one way to do it, there are probably about at least three others that jump to mind. 
Untested as no test data was provided.